Will a cell phone violation interfere with getting my pilots license?
Today I received a traffic ticket for using my cell phone while driving. This is the only ticket I have. Will this interfere with getting a pilot license?

This is in California. I got a using a cell phone while driving. First offence.

No. You don't even need to report it unless they took action against your license or required you to take a class. From the MedXPress guide:

Individual traffic arrests and/or convictions are not required to be
reported if they did not involve: alcohol or a drug; suspension, revocation, cancellation, or denial of driving privileges; or attendance at an educational or rehabilitation program.


No, a single ticket like that will be entirely inconsequential.
The FAA cares (a lot) about DUI tickets, and perhaps years of scofflaw behavior with repeated violations and a blatant pattern of incorrigible behavior might get their attention, but one traffic ticket? No issue whatsoever.

Just an FYI: "scofflaw" is not a term that's really known/used outside of NA.

@Jamiec Interesting, thanks.  Not a term that I use often enough to have learned that previously.  For other readers outside North America, dictionaries define it as "a contemptuous law violator" and "a person who flouts rules, conventions, or accepted practices."
